# Stretch the SVG To Viewport (container div) Disregarding Aspect Ration Set By viewBox

Tags: html, css, svg, browser

I've this inline [svg](http://jsbin.com/nuzogar/edit?html,css,js) on jsbin. It looks something like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 1080;" xml:space="preserve" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
// different svg element groups and paths
</svg>
```

As is clear from the [output](http://output.jsbin.com/nuzogar), that it is taking the viewport width, but it is not getting the viewport's height, and there is a white space beyond the height of svg (which is evident if one opens the dev tools and emulate iPad view or go full screen on chrome). What is needed of the expectation, is to have the svg fit the viewport.

The SVG has been exported such that the path photo frames and bulbs are relative to the whole svg viewbox coordinates. Because of which I do not have the option to separate out individual paths and plug and play with them, which would be needed for mobile view (Do I?) i.e. they are coupled to the viewBox size.

How can I get my svg to take viewport's width and size, for the desktop version atleast.

Comment: for svg try to add attribute preserveAspectRatio="none"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your SVG to fill the viewport height by setting a `vh` value for `height`

```
svg {
   height: 100vh; /* Fill entire viewport height */
}
```

This is going to mess with your aspect ratio though. Do you need to maintain aspect ratio or just get the SVG to fill the whole screen?

(also, to make sure you fill the whole screen you might want to get rid of the default margin `body {margin: 0;}` )

Comment: Hey @Digedu, thanks for answering! Yes it works, and answers my question. Aspect ratio would be killed yes, that's a bummer. I think I should ask my designer on the project to export the photo svg frames, bulbs and the wire separately, so that they are independent of how the background fills the viewport, and so that I am able to independently take care of the responsiveness of those independent svg images. Shan't I?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm quite new to SVG's on the web myself. If it were me trying to implement this I would cheat a little and not change the height of the SVG, but take advantage of the solid background colour: `body {background: #243347;}` Your viewers would be none the wiser ;)

Comment: that's the plan! Thanks :)